# LC_ALL error after updating ubuntu to 18.04 (from 17.10)

Tags: locale

After update I get this message box.

> Error found when loading ‘/etc/profile’
>
> ```
> locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale no such file or directory
> locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale no such file or directory
> ```
>
> As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
> You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

When I click <kbd>OK</kbd>, boot hangs, and I have to restart The computer, and the message reappears.

When in recovery mode I do a `locale` command, `LC_ALL` is blank, The rest has `nn_NO.utf8`

When I type `locale-gen` command I get

```
Cannot remove ‘usr/lib/locale/locale-archive’: Read-only file system
Generating locales
en_AU.UTF-8... cannot open local archive ‘usr/lib/locale/locale-archive’:
  Read-only file system
done
```

This message just repeats for each locale

What to do?

Comment: The message box should be a warning, and you ought to be able to log in the normal way. Once logged in, please run the command `cat /etc/profile` and show us what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: If the graphical login fails,  try to open a tty console with `Ctrl+Alt+F2` and log in there. I'm not quite sure what you should look for, though. If you edited `/etc/profile`, the error may be there, but I'm not quite sure. Did you do anything with your locale settings recently? If so, which file did you edit?

Comment: To those who want to close this due to it being a bug: There is no evidence that this is a bug. A broken locale may cause bad behavior in any version.

Comment: I have the same issue. I stopped my upgrade from 17.10 when it got stuck. Now I am not sure what is wrong. I am not able to install any software

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it sounds like the system is not even completing boot. Maybe OP should try again in recovery after remounting FS rw?

Comment: @Zanna: The "Error found..." message may show up only at session login (I know since I wrote that code), so to me it looks like the boot is completed. But since the OP does not respond to suggestions, he probably fixed the problem and moved on...

Answer (score 0):

I moved on after not being able to boot into the desktop.
Tried to correct and create a new locale from command, but failed - and ultimately did a complete reinstall.